# Creating a new data frame in R based on unique values and time stamp

Tags: r

I'm new to R, hence this elementary question.

I have a data frame with ~700 rows and 25 columns. Each row is a single appointment with the information about that appointment (time, priority, gender). The rows have a unique identifier in the form of a 7 digit number and there are multiple rows for the same identifier (when the same person came in for more than one appointment).

| ID | PRIORITY | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | Reading | 10/29 |
| 546 | Writing | 10/30 |
| 678 | Communication | 10/29 |
| 546 | Communication | 11/1 |
| 234 | Writing | 11/1 |

What I would like to do is create a new dataframe that has each unique ID along with the priority of their first visit, second visit, etc.

| ID | PRIORITY 1 | PRIORITY 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | Reading | Writing |
| 546 | Writing | Communication |
| 678 | Communication |  |

So far I have the list of all unique identifiers:

uniqueID <- unique(data$ID)

Now I would like to pull the data from PRIORITY based on these unique identifiers.

*Edit for better explanation of data:

| ID | PRIORITY | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 581205 | Communication | 2021-08-28 10:00:00 |
| 938596 | Reading | 2021-08-30 09:00:00 |
| 582948 | Writing | 2021-09-01 05:00:00 |
| 535893 | Reading | 2021-09-01 12:00:00 |
| 938596 | Writing | 2021-09-02 08:00:00 |
| 582948 | Communication | 2021-09-02 08:30:00 |
| 581205 | Writing | 2021-09-03 09:00:00 |
| 482940 | Reading | 2021-09-03 09:30:00 |

*Edit
Adding dput format:

```
data<- structure(list(ID = c(581205, 938596, 582948, 535893, 938596, 582948, 581205, 482940), PRIORITY = c("Communication", "Reading", "Writing", "Reading", "Writing", "Communication", "Writing", "Reading"), TIME = structure(c(1630144800, 1630314000, 1630472400, 1630497600, 1630569600, 1630571400, 1630659600, 1630661400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please don‘t put the data as table. Instead, please use `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(234, 546, 678, 546, 234),
                 PRIORITY = c("Reading", "Writing", "Communication", "Communication", "Writing"),
                 TIME = c("10/29", "10/30", "10/29", "11/1", "11/1"))

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ID_count = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID,
              values_from = c(PRIORITY, TIME),
              names_from = ID_count)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID PRIORITY_1    PRIORITY_2    TIME_1 TIME_2
  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>         <chr>  <chr> 
1   234 Reading       Writing       10/29  11/1  
2   546 Writing       Communication 10/30  11/1  
3   678 Communication <NA>          10/29  <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I'm looking for. I thought that my example was not too dumbed-down but when I run it on my dataset I get the error:

Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "function"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Impossible to say unless you are a) sharing a reproducible example of your data along with the exact code you were using. Please read this and update your question accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry about that, I will post a better example in the original post

Comment: Your updated example runs perfectly fine for me. What exact code were you rinning that gave you the error above?

Comment: I'm embarassed to admit that I had not changed the data from from 'df' to the name of my dataframe. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: If it's not too much to ask, is it possible to run the above chunk based on a conditional in a separate column? Basically, only pull the appointments where "Cancellation" == "FALSE"

Comment: Yes, please check the `filter` function from the tidyverse/dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

This would be another option also:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dummy_data <- data.frame(
"ID" = c(234,546,678,546,234),
"PRIORITY" = c("Reading","Writing","Communication","Communication","Writing"),
"TIME" = c("10/29","10/30","10/29","11/1","11/1"))

income_data_drop <- dummy_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "TIME", values_from = "PRIORITY")
income_data_drop

     ID    `10/29`      `10/30`   `11/1`       
    <dbl>   <chr>        <chr>     <chr>        
1   234    Reading       <NA>     Writing      
2   546     <NA>        Writing Communication
3   678  Communication   <NA>      <NA>
```